# Perfect Hashing Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, hash

Would a perfect hash have delete insert and search in 0(1) time? If so then why don't computer scientists use perfect hashing all the time if not what would be the time complexity?

Comment: Practical perfect hash functions for non-trivial ranges require all the keys to be known in advance. Obviously this is unsuitable for most hash function use cases. And not-so-perfect vanilla hash functions typically have O(1) performance over a large range of load factors, so the advantage of perfection is minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would a perfect hash have delete insert and search in 0(1) time?

Yes, as you'd get only one-element buckets. So you get as many buckets as there are elements.

> If so then why don't computer scientists use perfect hashing all the time if not what would be the time complexity?

One of the reasons is *theoretical*.
Perfect hash function is injective, and definition of such a function might be difficult if not impossible.

Consider following trivial structure:

```
{
  int x;
  int y;
}
```

Basically you want to have your `hash()` function to give unique results for every possible values of x and y, this might not be possible. Basically for trivial ones like `x + y`, `x * y`, `x ^ y`, you can always create another input that would give the same result.

On the other hand, it's possible (as `|N^2| = |N| = aleph-null`) - see [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).

The other of the reasons is *practical* - your return function has to have a return type. The return type would need to be capable of storing all possible injection results - so for hash of two 32-bit values it would need 64 bits, for three 3 * 32 etc. (compare that above mentioned pairing function effectively multiplies the arguments)

Comment: Quoting wikipedia: Whether this is the only polynomial pairing function is still an open question.

Comment: Your two reasons appear to be either-or, not both (unless I'm misunderstanding) - if the number of bits in the hash is the same as (or more than) the number of bits of the input (which appears to be what the last paragraph is talking about), it would be trivial to just use the input as the hash, which would be a perfect hash function (although, by implication, you'd also need a hash table that's big enough). If you're trying to represent it with *fewer* bits, then the first problem comes into play.

Comment: Excellent point! We can say that sizeof(output) = sizeof(input) = product(sizeof(arg[i])). And if that can be satisfied (what's not trivial in general, e.g. java's `hashCode` method returns `int`), then we can use the pairing function.

Comment: If you have a perfect hash function for N inputs, you'd need log(N) bits to address the table. Assuming you can compute the log(N) bit hash for an input in  time independent of N is a very string assumption!